# select center dropdown, not text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center a `select` using bootstrap, but I don't want to center the text inside the `select`. Does anybody know, how this is possible? I've tried to center the div and then set text-align to left for the `select`.

```
 <div class="form-group" align="center">
  <label for"year">Årstal</label><br />
  <select style="text-align:left;" class="selectpicker" multiple title="Vælg et eller flere årstal">
    <option>40</option>
    <option>41</option>
    <option>42</option>
    <option>43</option>
    <option>44</option>
    <option>45</option>
  </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try centering the div via `css`, and then use the `dir` attribute of the `select`.

```
<select dir="ltr" class="selectpicker" multiple title="Vælg et eller flere årstal">
    <option>40</option>
    <option>41</option>
    <option>42</option>
    <option>43</option>
</select>
```

For more information, look here:
http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/select.html